# Hero animation producing RenderBox overflow

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the `Hero` component to create an animation between two pages.
The `Hero` component is used to wrap an `Image` widget (no problem) and a `Container` widget (problematic).

[image: screen capture]

The following overflow error is thrown:

```
 ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 4256): The following message was thrown during layout:
I/flutter ( 4256): A RenderFlex overflowed by 104 pixels on the right.
```

#### First page

```
Positioned(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.45,
  top: 160.0,
  left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.04,
  child: Hero(
     tag: i.id, 
     child: Container( ...)
  )
)
```

#### Second page

```
Hero(
  tag: this.i.departure,
  child: Container(
     margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25),
     height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
     decoration: cardDecoration,
   ),
 ),
```

Answer (score 22):

The reason for this is not the `Container` widget itself, it is the content.
The GIF you shared clearly shows that the `Text` inside it is not rendered as usual but overly large. This is caused by a missing `Material` ancestor, which would contain the necessary [`InheritedWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html)'s to render the `Text` properly (it is missing because `Hero` places the `child` you supply in the `Overlay` and there it does not inherit a `Material` from your `Scaffold`).

Hence, you need to add a `Material` widget to fix your issue.

```dart
Hero(
  tag: tag,
  child: Material(
    type: MaterialType.transparency,
    child: .. // in your cause `Container(..)`
  ),
)
```

I supplied [`MaterialType.transparency`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialType-class.html) to prevent it from affecting the underlying UI.

Comment: Nice catch (+1), what's the difference between `MaterialType.transparency` and setting `color` as `Colors.transparent` in the `Material` widget.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad It is [handled differently inside of `_MaterialState`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/577c2fc48cbdd7d843a15673c6bb65006e4ae1c1/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/material.dart#L379), i.e. it just drops unneeded attributes connected to the animation and background.

Comment: I added the Material Widget as you did to wrap both containers on both pages, but it didn't fix the problem. The same overflow happens :/

Comment: Yes, still exaclty the same. Here's the full code of both files : https://codeshare.io/2jEJD3 https://codeshare.io/50wZJg

Answer (score 7):

I found [this issue on Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27320), so I added this property to the Hero Widget:

```
flightShuttleBuilder: (BuildContext flightContext,
                                Animation<double> animation,
                                HeroFlightDirection flightDirection,
                                BuildContext fromHeroContext,
                                BuildContext toHeroContext,){

                              return SingleChildScrollView(
                                child: fromHeroContext.widget,
                              );},
```

and the visual error disappeared. There is still an error that displays in the terminal :

```
I/flutter ( 8073): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 8073): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter ( 8073): RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
I/flutter ( 8073): When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example if it is
I/flutter ( 8073): in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a
I/flutter ( 8073): flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining
I/flutter ( 8073): space in the vertical direction.
I/flutter ( 8073): These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child
I/flutter ( 8073): cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.
I/flutter ( 8073): Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible
I/flutter ( 8073): children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size
I/flutter ( 8073): themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and
I/flutter ( 8073): then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum
I/flutter ( 8073): constraints provided by the parent.
I/flutter ( 8073): The affected RenderFlex is:
I/flutter ( 8073):   RenderFlex#2944e relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8073): The creator information is set to:
I/flutter ( 8073):   Column ← ContentTripTease ← DecoratedBox ← Container ← KeyedSubtree-[GlobalKey#338b3] ← Hero ←
I/flutter ( 8073):   _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#e8b80] ← Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics
I/flutter ( 8073):   ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#1b5ab] ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 8073): The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded width constraint is:
I/flutter ( 8073):   _RenderSingleChildViewport#43f3a NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8073):   creator: _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#e8b80] ← Semantics ← Listener ←
I/flutter ( 8073):   _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#1b5ab] ←
I/flutter ( 8073):   Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#62cca] ← RepaintBoundary ← CustomPaint ←
I/flutter ( 8073):   RepaintBoundary ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 8073):   parentData: <none> (can use size)
I/flutter ( 8073):   constraints: BoxConstraints(w=258.8, h=341.4)
I/flutter ( 8073):   size: MISSING
I/flutter ( 8073): See also: https://flutter.dev/layout/
I/flutter ( 8073): If this message did not help you determine the problem, consider using debugDumpRenderTree():
I/flutter ( 8073):   https://flutter.dev/debugging/#rendering-layer
I/flutter ( 8073):   http://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/debugDumpRenderTree.html
I/flutter ( 8073): If none of the above helps enough to fix this problem, please don't hesitate to file a bug:
I/flutter ( 8073):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
I/flutter ( 8073): 
I/flutter ( 8073): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 8073): #0      RenderFlex.performLayout.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:690:11)
I/flutter ( 8073): #1      RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:711:10)
I/flutter ( 8073): #2      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter ( 8073): #3      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 8073): #4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter ( 8073): #5      _RenderSingleChildViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/single_child_scroll_view.dart:497:13)
I/flutter ( 8073): #6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter ( 8073): #7      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 8073): #8      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter ( 8073): #9      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 8073): #10     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter ( 8073): #11     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 8073): #12     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter ( 8073): #13     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 8073): #14     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter ( 8073): #15     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 8073): #16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter ( 8073): #17     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 8073): #18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter ( 8073): #19     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 8073): #20     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter ( 8073): #21     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 8073): #22     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter ( 8073): #23     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 8073): #24     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter ( 8073): #25     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 8073): #26     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter ( 8073): #27     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 8073): #28     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter ( 8073): #29     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 8073): #30     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1644:7)
I/flutter ( 8073): #31     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:549:15)
I/flutter ( 8073): #32     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1519:7)
I/flutter ( 8073): #33     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:766:18)
I/flutter ( 8073): #34     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:347:19)
I/flutter ( 8073): #35     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:701:13)
I/flutter ( 8073): #36     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:286:5)
I/flutter ( 8073): #37     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1012:15)
I/flutter ( 8073): #38     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:952:9)
I/flutter ( 8073): #39     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:864:5)
I/flutter ( 8073): #43     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:219:10)
I/flutter ( 8073): #44     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:178:3)
I/flutter ( 8073): (elided 3 frames from package dart:async)
I/flutter ( 8073):
I/flutter ( 8073): The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired:
I/flutter ( 8073):   RenderFlex#2944e relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8073):   creator: Column ← ContentTripTease ← DecoratedBox ← Container ← KeyedSubtree-[GlobalKey#338b3] ←
I/flutter ( 8073):   Hero ← _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#e8b80] ← Semantics ← Listener ←
I/flutter ( 8073):   _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#1b5ab] ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 8073):   parentData: <none> (can use size)
I/flutter ( 8073):   constraints: BoxConstraints(w=258.8, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
I/flutter ( 8073):   size: MISSING
I/flutter ( 8073):   direction: vertical
I/flutter ( 8073):   mainAxisAlignment: start
I/flutter ( 8073):   mainAxisSize: max
I/flutter ( 8073):   crossAxisAlignment: center
I/flutter ( 8073):   verticalDirection: down
I/flutter ( 8073): This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth 5):
I/flutter ( 8073):   RenderPadding#7266f relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8073):     RenderFlex#36165 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8073):       RenderPadding#35f21 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8073):         RenderParagraph#a364d relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8073):       RenderPadding#8a295 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8073):         RenderFlex#59634 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8073):           RenderPadding#2ff9e relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8073):           RenderPadding#17df3 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8073):           RenderPadding#f9eb4 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8073):   RenderConstrainedBox#cf91c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8073):     RenderPadding#9142e NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8073):       RenderSemanticsAnnotations#09e8c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8073):         _RenderInputPadding#a87c6 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8073):           RenderConstrainedBox#07355 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8073): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Is this error a big problem ?

Comment: Thanks. This helped me!!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who comes to this question, I have researched on Hero widget for tens of hours. I ended up finish this in this way.

## Why getting the error

Hero widget will scale from the widget you click, to the widget you will navigate to. So in the process of  transition, your widget will be constrained and cramed in a little box, which has a small size. And if you use a widget with fixed size, like `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25`, which uses a device screen size. It's likely to get that error.

## How to solve it

To solve it, make sure every children of the Hero that you are navigate to has a flex size. For example, wrap every child in a `Row` with a `Expanded` and use `flex`, which will divide into multiple part by flex number. Or use `FractionallySizedBox`.

## Think twice when you use Hero.

Finally I found that Actually what I want to use is `OpenContainer` in a package called **animations**. Check it [animations](https://pub.dev/packages/animations) before using.

Comment: that didn't help